# How to get the return array back from an ajax function call using jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
var testFile = $("#selection").val(),
    testData = getTestData(testFile); 

// not working during the first time I run the function, empty
alert(testData); 

function getTestData(testF) {
    $.getJSON("test.php", {
        fileTest: testF
    }, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            if (value != "") {} else {
                testArray[index] = value;
            }
        });
    });

    // working I see the values
    alert(testArray); 

    // not working the first time running this function
    return testArray; 
}​
```

Comment: AJAX is so misunderstood.... there must be a million threads on SO about this "problem" so just do some searching. I bet the related column to the right can help you ----->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***AJAX is asynchronous*** .. So your function must have returned before the values were stored into it..

Better to store it in a higher scoped variable and use it once the request is done..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to handle the returned array and do whatever you need to do with it within the callback function of `getJSON()`.

The reason you are getting empty values is because your return testArray, is likley executing before the `getJSON` call and callback function have finished executing.

This is because that method is executed asynchronously.  You will need to do whatever you need to do with the data within the callback function.